# How to generate combinations obtained by permuting 2 positions in Java

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

I have this problem, I need to generate from a given permutation not all combinations, but just those obtained after permuting 2 positions and without repetition. It's called the region of the a given permutation, for example given 1234 I want to generate :

2134

3214

4231

1324

1432

1243

the size of the region of any given permutation is , n(n-1)/2 , in this case it's 6 combinations .

Now, I have this programme , he does a little too much then what I want, he generates all 24 possible combinations :

```
public class PossibleCombinations {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Entrer a mumber");
       int n=s.nextInt();

        int[] currentab = new int[n];
        // fill in the table 1 TO N 
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            currentab[i - 1] = i;
        }

        int total = 0;

        for (;;) {
            total++;

            boolean[] used = new boolean[n + 1];
            Arrays.fill(used, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print(currentab[i] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();

            used[currentab[n - 1]] = false;

            int pos = -1;
            for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {              
                used[currentab[i]] = false;

                if (currentab[i] < currentab[i + 1]) {
                    pos = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (pos == -1) {
                break;
            }               

            for (int i = currentab[pos] + 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (!used[i]) {
                    currentab[pos] = i;
                    used[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (!used[i]) {
                    currentab[++pos] = i;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(total);
    }       


}
```

the Question is how can I fix this programme to turn it into a programme that generates only the combinations wanted .

Comment: I am not sure where to start, it is far more complicated than it need to be.  You know you have to swap two places, and this take two looks to iterate through all the combinations.  You don't need to check for duplicates because you can generate them in such a way that they can't duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple like

```
public static void printSwapTwo(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1;i++)
       for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
          // gives all the pairs of i and j without repeats 
          sb.setLength(0);
          for(int k = 1; k <= n; k++) sb.append(k);
          char tmp = sb.charAt(i);
          sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(j));
          sb.setCharAt(j, tmp);
          System.out.println(sb);
          count++;
       }
    System.out.println("total=" + count+" and should be " + n * (n - 1) / 2);
 }
```